# Bootstrap buttons not working on mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Basically I am making a website and it works all fine until you try press the button on mobile chrome however it does work on mobile safari and desktop chrome.

Here is my button code there pretty much all the same:

`<button style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;" type="button" id="MenuButton " class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Menu</button>`

and here is my javascript/ jquery:

```
$("#MenuButton").click(function(){
    location.href = "menu.html";
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

What I have found is Chrome Extensions don't allow you to have inline JavaScript [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution). And its same for Firefox.

So try using external Javascript if you are using inline Js.

```js
$("#MenuButton").click(function(){
    location.href = "menu.html";
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;" type="button" id="MenuButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Menu</button>
```

Comment: I have added the bootstrap and jquery library I probably should have said that and it doesn't seem the space did anything also the click does work on desktop chrome and mobile safari but its not working on mobile chrome.

Comment: Are u Using Inline javascript ?

Comment: I am using the form where it is in a separate file but linked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(document).on("click", "#MenuButton",function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.yourdomain.com/menu.html";
    });
```

If you are rendering the button as dynamic element, it will not be captured on first load. So you need to use .on

If still not working, try below

```
$(document).on("click", "#MenuButton",function(){
            alert("ok")
        });
```

You should get an alert box.

If not, open inspect element -> console and post the error you see